# Probability inequalities

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, probability-inequalities, moment-generating-function

I am looking for some probability inequalities for sums of unbounded random variables. I would really appreciate it if anyone can provide me some thoughts.

My problem is to find an exponential upper bound over the probability that the sum of unbounded i.i.d. random variables, which are in fact the multiplication of two i.i.d. Gaussian, exceeds some certain value, i.e., $\mathrm{Pr}[ X  \geq \epsilon\sigma^2 N] \leq \exp(?)$, where $X = \sum_{i=1}^{N} w_iv_i$, $w_i$ and $v_i$ are generated i.i.d. from $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma)$.

I tried to use the Chernoff bound using moment generating function (MGF), the derived bound is given by:

$\begin{eqnarray}
\mathrm{Pr}[ X  \geq \epsilon\sigma^2 N] &\leq& \min\limits_s \exp(-s\epsilon\sigma^2 N)g_X(s) \\
 &=& \exp\left(-\frac{N}{2}\left(\sqrt{1+4\epsilon^2} -1 + \log(\sqrt{1+4\epsilon^2}-1) - \log(2\epsilon^2)\right)\right)
\end{eqnarray}$

where $g_X(s) = \left(\frac{1}{1-\sigma^4 s^2}\right)^{\frac{N}{2}}$ is the MGF of $X$. But the bound is not so tight. The main issue in my problem is that the random variables are unbounded, and unfortunately I can not use the bound of Hoeffding inequality.

I will be to happy if you help me find some tight exponential bound.

Comment: Have you tried truncating the random variables?

Comment: I did not use, can you propose me a book or a paper to know how to do this.

Comment: @Farzad, if you do not get answers here try math.SE or mathoverflow.net. Why do you have sum of *product* of normal variable, is there a special reason? Also can you elaborate more on what tightness of the bound means?

Comment: Sounds like a compressed-sensing related problem. Look up R. Vershynin's notes on nonasymptotic random matrix theory, specifically the bounds on what he calls *subexponential* random variables. That'll get you started. If you need more pointers, let us know and I'll try to post some more info.

Comment: There are at least a couple related questions and answers on this topic on math.SE (disclaimer: including one I participated in).

Comment: The product $w_i v_i$ has as a 'normal product' distribution. I believe the the mean of this product is zero and the variance is $\sigma^4$ where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of $w_i$ and $v_i$. For $N$ largeish, you could use the central limit theorem to get approximate norality of $X$. If you can compute the skew of the normal product distribution, I believe you can apply the Berry-Esseen theorem to bound the rate of convergence of the CDF.

Comment: @shabbychef, Berry-Esseen has pretty slow convergence, since it's a uniform bound over the class of all distribution functions $F$.

Comment: **Related**: (see link in answer) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35114/how-to-obtain-tail-bounds-for-a-square-of-sub-gaussian-random-variable

Comment: @shabbychef, Thanks for your comment, but as cardinal said the bound is not exponential and it is not useful for me.

Comment: Alexander Barvinok also has some nice measure concentration notes at http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~barvinok/total710.pdf that may be of use.

Comment: @Farzad, perhaps you can edit your question and give the explicit statement of the bound you have but are unsatisfied with. That would provide a good reference point.

Comment: @ cardinal, I put the bound I derived, you can check it now.

Comment: Ah, I see, of course. Perhaps abuse Cauchy Schwarz, and look at $X$ as a dot product, and use the CDF of the Chi square distribution. The problem is that this throws away the cosine of the angle, (i.e. assumes it is 1), which may give a too weak bound.

Comment: @Farzad  Are you sure about your calculation of the value of $s$ that minimizes your upper bound?  You should be getting two roots of a quadratic in $s$ where the extremum occurs, and perhaps you are picking the wrong one?<br>  There are some results in the communications systems literature that say that in some cases Chernoff bounds are exponentially tight, and if these are applicable here, then the search for a tighter exponential bound than Chernoff would be futile.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: This last statement is a little bit of a curious one, especially considering that the (unmodified) Chernoff bound is nowhere tight in the simple case of a zero-mean Gaussian random variable and, indeed, has unbounded relative error asymptotically.

Comment: @cardinal  I am aware of the looseness of the Chernoff bound for zero-mean Gaussian random variables.  My statement is a regurgitation of what I had read long ago in a classic text "Principles of Communication Engineering" by Wozencraft and Jacobs.  Now that I looked at the book again, I see that they cite a note by R. G. Gallager in MIT Res. Lab. Elect. Quarterly Prog. Rept, April 1965, and unpublished seminar notes by C. E. Shannonn in 1956 as the source of the claim.  I myself have not read either document, but am inclined to believe the result even if it is not directly applicable here.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Sorry that I am just now seeing your comment from awhile ago. I think you might be interested in the following little paper, which I've linked to a couple of times on math.SE as well: T. K. Phillips and R. Nelson (1995), [The moment bound is tighter than Chernoff's bound for positive tail probabilities](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2684633), *The American Statistician*, vol 42, no. 2., 175-178.

Comment: This paper seems to address the same problem you have. Hope you may find it helpful. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10986-008-9007-7

Comment: What about the Gaussian Concentration inequality? (https://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/386/Concentration.pdf) It's an exponential bound, and it works for any lipschitz function.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Chernoff bound you suggested for some $s\le 1/(2\sigma^2)$ that will be specified later,
\[ 
P[X>t] \le \exp(-st) \exp\Big(-(N/2) \log(1-\sigma^4s^2) \Big) \le \exp(-st + \sigma^4s^2 N)
\]
where the second inequality holds thanks to $-\log(1-x)\le 2x$ for any $x\in(0,1/2)$. Now take  $t=\epsilon \sigma^2 N$ and $s=t/(2\sigma^4N)$, the right hand side becomes $\exp(-t^2/(4\sigma^4N)=\exp(-\epsilon^2 N/4)$ which yields
\[
P[X>\epsilon \sigma^2 N] \le \exp(-\epsilon^2 N/4).
\]
for any $\epsilon\in(0,1)$.

Another avenue is to directly apply concentration inequalities such as the Hanson-Wright inequality, or concentration inequalities for Gaussian chaos of order 2 which encompasses the random variable you are interested in.

#### Simpler approach without using the moment generating function

Take $\sigma=1$ for simplicity (otherwise, one may rescale by dividing by $\sigma^2$).

Write $v=(v_1,...,v_n)^T$ and $w=(w_1,...,w_n)^T$. You are asking for upper bounds
on $P(v^Tw>\epsilon N)$.

Let $Z= w^T v/\|v\|$. Then $Z\sim N(0,1)$ by independence of $v,w$
and $\|v\|^2$ is independent of $Z$ with the $\chi^2$ distribution with $n$ degrees-of-freedom.

By standard bounds on standard normal and $\chi^2$ random variables,
$$P(|Z|>\epsilon\sqrt{n/2})\le 2\exp(-\epsilon^2 n/4),
\qquad\qquad
P(\|v\|>\sqrt{2n}) \le \exp(-n(\sqrt 2 -1)^2/2).
$$
Combining with the union bound gives an upper bound on $P(v^Tw>\epsilon N)$
of the form $ 2\exp(-\epsilon^2 n/4) + \exp(-n(\sqrt 2 -1)^2/2)$.

Answer (score 0):

The bound you obtain is of order $e^{-\epsilon}$ as $\epsilon \to \infty$. I don't think you can do much better for general $\epsilon$. From the [Wikipedia page on Product Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution#Independent_Central-Normal_Distributions) the distribution of $w_i v_i$ is $K_0(z)/\pi$ where $K_0$ is a modified Bessel function. From (10.25.3) in the [DLMF function list](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.25#E3), $K_0(t) \sim e^{-t}/\sqrt{t}$ so that for $x$ sufficiently large $\mathbb{P}(w_i v_i > x) \sim \int_x^\infty e^{-t}/\sqrt{t} dt$ which is not going to give you a sub-Gaussian bound.